# Is it possible to implement a test for `T.clone` for `T: Copy`

Tags: rust

The documentation for `Copy` outlines the requirements for the `Clone` implementation if a type also implements `Copy`

> `Clone` is a supertrait of `Copy`, so everything which is `Copy` must also implement `Clone`. If a type is `Copy` then its `Clone` implementation only needs to return `*self` (see the example above).

This is easy to check in code review or using [clippy](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/expl_impl_clone_on_copy), but I am wondering if it is also possible to write a test to check it.

My first thought is that since `Copy` is a simple bit-wise copy, I can inspect the byte contents of a reference, and `assert_eq!(bit_contents(&t), bit_contents(&t.clone()))`. However, I think `bit_contents` may be potentially unsound since the struct may have uninitialized memory (if it contains a smaller variant of a `union` or `enum`).

Is my understanding correct? Are there other ways to ensure that a `Clone` trait is implemented correctly for `T: Copy`?

(This question is mostly for understanding of Rust's memory handling, for practical purposes I am happy to just use the clippy lint)

Comment: FWIW even if the bitwise representation of the returned objects are the same, `clone` may have side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is undefined behavior to read padding bytes, and even if it was not (for example, you compare them using inline assembly or a call to `memcmp()`), padding bytes are not initialized, which means that the compiler is free to not copy them, which will result in different values for padding bytes, thus comparison failure.

As far as I know there is no way to test that in Rust, aside from providing a derive macro that will recursively compare all primitive fields.